# Is this considered "rep farming"?

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

I found [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13045080) where the editor in question has proposed to change a variable name. It is not in conflict with the answerer's intent as demonstrated by [the comment from the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587590/correct-way-to-post-binary-data-using-retrofit-2-0/36587686#comment60774068_36587686):

> Oh my mistake change `uploadThumbnail(partFile);` to `uploadThumbnail(fbody);`

Since the answerer has already clarified this, and has not chosen to edit the answer, what's the correct response for this edit review?

Comment: for ONCE, we get an edit that touches code for the right reason, MENTIONS the comment... and we still want to say no?..... sigh....

Comment: And the proposal isn't to change a variable name, but to call the method with the PROPER variable. This is way more than esthetics...

Comment: @Patrice I'm aware it's more than aesthetics, but isn't that edit the answerer's responsibility?

Comment: *Maybe* you can make a case about the author not editing being a signal to not edit (I disagree), by why do you think this is rep farming?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ideally, yes. If the answerer doesn't do it, isn't it more valuable to have it in the answer as opposed to in a comment?

Comment: @davidism Because you get reputation when you make edits before you have the privilege to make them without review. This edit could be considered unnecessary since it is already clarified in the comments.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Comments can be deleted at any time. The answer is expected to be in the answer.

Comment: I'd be one of the most hopeless rep whores if such an edit was for rep farming.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Since the answerer has already clarified this, and has not chosen to edit the answer, what's the correct response for this edit review?

Approve the edit.  One of the primary purposes of editing is to move relevant information the post author has posted in comments into the answer itself, which is done entirely appropriately here.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't want to make any assumptions about the policy, which is why I asked about it here. Now I'm aware of the review-process preference.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You don't need to make assumptions about it, you just need to read the help center.  It's pretty explicit.

Answer (score 11):

"Rep farming" would be making quick, simple, low quality edits over and over again with the intention of gaining rep without effort and with no real benefit to the posts.

This user on the other hand obviously put in effort by reading and understanding the comments and making a valid change with a relevant explanation.  The fact that they got rep for it does not make it farming.

Comment: Rep gardening. Organic, from heirloom seed, using my own compost, pollinated by the bees in the back field, gardening.

Comment: @JoshCaswell at least you are using high quality manure, right?

Comment: @Braiam that`s the fun of working on Stack... the site has an endless production of sh.... I mean... manure-worthy questions :D